# awk to compare files

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to use awk to find the common lines between two files and save it as a .txt as follows:

```
>CL1 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
>CL2 1
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8
```

```
>CL1 1
ler_1 lcu_2 ler_3
>CL2 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
>CL3 1
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8
```

Expected output with the two common "CL's":

```
>CL1 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
>CL2 1
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8
```

The code I'm using:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1.cls file2.cls > out.txt
```

Actual output:

```
CL1 1
CL2 1
```

Does anyone know to solve this?

Comment: Why isn't `lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8` in the expected output?

Comment: I get ```>CL1 1
>CL2 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8```

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I write the output twice. I'll fix it.

Comment: @anubhava I think it works. My files are lot bigger than I wrote here, so I'm still having a giant output only with CL and the numbers (CL1 1, CL2 1..). Do you know how can I keep only the names (lcu_1, lcu_2, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk, can use `>` as the *record* separator. The output is a bit messed up though:

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS = ORS = ">"} NR == FNR {clu[$1]; next} $1 in clu' file2.cls file1.cls
>CL1 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
>CL2 1
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8
>⏎
```

My shell outputs `⏎` to indicate no trailing newline.

Cleaning up the output:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {RS = ">"}
    NR == FNR {clu[$1]; next}
    length($1) && $1 in clu {gsub(/^\n|\n$/, ""); print ">" $0}
' file2.cls file1.cls
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3` appears before `>CL2 1` in your first file but after it in the second. I shall assume you don't care about ordering.

You don't specify what should happen if a file contains duplicate/identical lines. I shall assume only one copy is required.

The unix utility `comm` finds common/distinct lines in two sorted files:

```
comm -12 <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)
```

giving:

```
>CL1 1
>CL2 1
lcu_1 lcu_2 lcu_3
lcu_6 lcu_4 lcu_8
```